Getting a 403 Forbidden accessing Swagger UI in Django REST Framework behind Basic Auth
I am deploying a Django Rest Framework application. The application runs under gunicorn (port 8000) which is proxied by Apache. (I need to use Apache due to some authentication requirements in certain parts of the application.)
The following Apache configuration fragment works:
  <Location "/api/v1/schema">
    Require all granted
    #
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000/api/v1/schema
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/api/v1/schema
  </Location>

However, the following gives me a "403 Forbidden" error in my browser:
  <Location "/api/v1/schema">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "MyAPI Swagger UI"
    AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/swagger.htpasswd
    Require valid-user
    #
    ProxyPass        http://localhost:8000/api/v1/schema
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8000/api/v1/schema
  </Location>

The error I see in the Apache log is
myapi.example.com:443 130.211.2.57 - swagger [21/Jul/2024:18:51:59 +0000] "GET /api/v1/schema/swagger-ui/ HTTP/1.1" 403 378 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/126.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

I see this from gunicorn:
Forbidden: /api/v1/schema/swagger-ui/

In case it is relevant, here is what I have in the Django settings file related to drf:

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS': 'drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema',
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ['django_filters.rest_framework.DjangoFilterBackend'],
}

UPDATE. Kyell asked for the views file for /api/v1/schema/swagger-ui/. That view comes with drf_spectacular. Runnin the showurls actions I see this route:
/api/v1/schema/swagger-ui/  drf_spectacular.views.SpectacularSwaggerView  swagger-ui

Looking at the code for the file views.py in the drf_spectacular module I see this:
class SpectacularSwaggerView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
    permission_classes = spectacular_settings.SERVE_PERMISSIONS
    authentication_classes = AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES
    url_name: str = 'schema'
    url: Optional[str] = None
    template_name: str = 'drf_spectacular/swagger_ui.html'
    template_name_js: str = 'drf_spectacular/swagger_ui.js'
    title: str = spectacular_settings.TITLE

    @extend_schema(exclude=True)
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return Response(
            data={
                'title': self.title,
                'swagger_ui_css': self._swagger_ui_resource('swagger-ui.css'),
                'swagger_ui_bundle': self._swagger_ui_resource('swagger-ui-bundle.js'),
                'swagger_ui_standalone': self._swagger_ui_resource('swagger-ui-standalone-preset.js'),
                'favicon_href': self._swagger_ui_favicon(),
                'schema_url': self._get_schema_url(request),
                'settings': self._dump(spectacular_settings.SWAGGER_UI_SETTINGS),
                'oauth2_config': self._dump(spectacular_settings.SWAGGER_UI_OAUTH2_CONFIG),
                'template_name_js': self.template_name_js,
                'csrf_header_name': self._get_csrf_header_name(),
                'schema_auth_names': self._dump(self._get_schema_auth_names()),
            },
            template_name=self.template_name,
            headers={
                "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "unsafe-none",
            }
        )

    def _dump(self, data):
        return data if isinstance(data, str) else json.dumps(data, indent=2)

    def _get_schema_url(self, request):
        schema_url = self.url or get_relative_url(reverse(self.url_name, request=request))
        return set_query_parameters(
            url=schema_url,
            lang=request.GET.get('lang'),
            version=request.GET.get('version')
        )

    def _get_csrf_header_name(self):
        csrf_header_name = settings.CSRF_HEADER_NAME
        if csrf_header_name.startswith('HTTP_'):
            csrf_header_name = csrf_header_name[5:]
        return csrf_header_name.replace('_', '-')

    def _get_schema_auth_names(self):
        from drf_spectacular.extensions import OpenApiAuthenticationExtension
        if spectacular_settings.SERVE_PUBLIC:
            return []
        auth_extensions = [
            OpenApiAuthenticationExtension.get_match(klass)
            for klass in self.authentication_classes
        ]
        return [auth.name for auth in auth_extensions if auth]

    @staticmethod
    def _swagger_ui_resource(filename):
        if spectacular_settings.SWAGGER_UI_DIST == 'SIDECAR':
            return _get_sidecar_url(f'swagger-ui-dist/{filename}')
        return f'{spectacular_settings.SWAGGER_UI_DIST}/{filename}'

    @staticmethod
    def _swagger_ui_favicon():
        if spectacular_settings.SWAGGER_UI_FAVICON_HREF == 'SIDECAR':
            return _get_sidecar_url('swagger-ui-dist/favicon-32x32.png')
        return spectacular_settings.SWAGGER_UI_FAVICON_HREF



Could you provide the view for /api/v1/schema/swagger-ui/, DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES would only apply to views that use rest_framework's classes/decorators

Updated the question with views.py from drf_spectacular.
